# Compare date difference with pandas timestamp values

Tags: pandas, python-2.7

I'm trying to perform specific operations based on the age of data in days within a dataframe. What I am looking for is something like as follows:

```py
import pandas as pd

if 10days < (pd.Timestamp.now() - pd.Timestamp(2019, 3, 20)):
    print 'The data is older than 10 days'
```

Is there something I can replace "10days" with or some other way I can perform operations based on the difference between two Timestamp values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is `pd.Timedelta('10D')`, `pd.Timedelta(10, unit='D')` (or `unit='days'` or `unit='day'`), or `pd.Timedelta(days=10)`. For example,

```
In [37]: pd.Timedelta(days=10) < pd.Timestamp.now() - pd.Timestamp(2019, 3, 20)
Out[37]: False

In [38]: pd.Timedelta(days=5) < pd.Timestamp.now() - pd.Timestamp(2019, 3, 20)
Out[38]: True
```